# iOS websql limit

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, web-sql

I am currently programming a catalog app with html, css, js and cordova - the user fills the catalog with categories and products and the he clicks a sync-button in the app and the app downloads all the data in json format. then I sort this data and store them in a websql-database.

Every product has a image and i send this image with the json file in base64 and on the device I save the base64 string in the database.

But I red, that the websql limit on iOS is 50mb and this is not enought because I get the 50mb after about 20 products.

The biggest Problem is, that the app have to run also when the user is offline. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use cordova-sqlite, so you use native sqlite databases instead of the webkit, and you can get all the space available in the device.

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage